# Delta total line current - Basic electricity problem

Tags: current, delta

I'm reading the book ***Basic Electricity*** from *Milton Gussow* and there's a problem that is driving me crazy, I'm not able to get the result.
Can anyone provide me with a guideline to resolve it?

This is the problem:[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs phasors because your motors take a little inductive currents and the lamps act as resistors. The motors are Y-loads but the lamps are a D-load, which cause harmful interline currents. Fortunately the lamp banks are identical, so the equivalent resistive Y-load exists. Find it and add the single line currents as phasors. Note that delta to Y transform is not a must, it only makes the number of needed phasors a little smaller.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, why the Y-loads and the D-loads?  I'm trying to do this: Motor 1: 15A * 0.8 + Motor 2: 20A * 0.95 + 24.5A, after that I get the inductive currents of the motors and get the resulting current with: amp = sqrt(x^2+y^2).

Comment: @Ricky2  lamp banks are between the lines. That is delta. Y is 3 loads, one end of each is at a line, the other ends are all together. Instead of 24.5A you should use squareroot (3)*24.5A because that is the effective one line current.